# DataGridview New Row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a perfectly functioning `DataGridView` in a C# Winforms Application.

The form adds, deletes or modifies existing items in the grid.

The problem I'm having is that when I cursor into the new row, then back out as I'm sure a user will, it triggers a change in the last row of existing data via the `Dataset.Tables[1].GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified)`

It does not trigger a `Dataset.Tables[1].GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)`

When looking at the `DataRowVersion.Original` vs the `DataRowVersion.Current` all items are identical. Any ideas?

Comment: Call `yourGrid.EndEdit();` beforehand. Don't forget to call `yourDataTable.AcceptChanges();` when you first time fill it, and when you successfully update the db.

Comment: My current code includes your suggestions. The odd part of the entire issue is the data table the grid is based on shows a current and original values as identical, even though it’s flagged by the GetChanges row modified. My current workaround is a data row extension method the compares original and current, if they are identical then disregard the changes. Not ideal.